# Is it possible speed up the drop of annotation in MKMapView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have something like 30 annotations in my map and I want speed up the dropping animation.

Is it possible speed up the drop of annotation in MKMapView or drop all of them at once?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement your own drop animation in the `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method.  You should also set `animatesDrop` to `NO` to avoid a possible double animation.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)annotationViews
{
    NSTimeInterval delayInterval = 0;

    for (MKAnnotationView *annView in annotationViews)
    {
        CGRect endFrame = annView.frame;

        annView.frame = CGRectOffset(endFrame, 0, -500);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.125 
                              delay:delayInterval
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                         animations:^{ annView.frame = endFrame; } 
                         completion:NULL];

        delayInterval += 0.0625;
    }
}
```

This drops the annotations at a rate you specify.

To drop them all at once, hard-code the `delay` parameter to `0.0` instead of the incrementing `delayInterval`.

Comment: I tried this, but some of pins are dropping with high velocity, but other dropping with default speed...
I tried to set 0.0 to delayInterval, but the pins is not dropping all at once too...

Comment: I am not able to exactly duplicate the problems you see but: are the annotations being added in separate batches or in a single method call?  If in separate method calls, try first adding the annotations to an NSMutableArray and then call addAnnotations with the array to add all at once.  Or, do you have any other time consuming processing going on at the same time as the annotations are added?

Comment: I did what you said.
Added all the pins in a NSMutableArray and then added it with the method addAnnotationS. And nothing changed.

And I dont't have any other process going at the same time. I'm doing something like this:

adding all the pins in a method before he delegate is called:

Comment: so in the delegate, I just do the last configurations for my annotations and return a MKPinAnnotationView.

Comment: Make sure animatesDrop is set to NO in viewForAnnotation.  If it is but you still see the problem, try creating a separate app that just has the map and adds the annotations using some hard-coded coordinates.  It might help isolate the cause.  Are you testing on device or simulator?  What iOS version?